# Проверка слова "начинают"

Tags: морфология

Как проверить слово "начинают"?

Answer (score 1):

Зачин (начало былины или сказки); трудовой почин.

Answer (score 0):

В корнях чин, чит, жим пишется и, так как есть суффикс а.